# ¿Como comparar datos de dos arreglos de objetos?

Tags: javascript, array

Tengo 3 arreglos de objetos, son dos diferentes y el tercero se compone de la mezcla de los otros dos.

Trato de hacer una comparación recoriendo los tres pero no me funciona, pasare algo de los arreglos para que se entienda un poco (*no es una prueba tecnica, me la consegui por ahi para practicar*).

El codigo deberia darme los nombres de los campos con los nobres de sus administradores.

```js
const paddockManagers = [{
    id: 1,
    taxNumber: "132254524",
    name: "JUAN TAPIA BURGOS"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    taxNumber: "143618668",
    name: "EFRAIN SOTO VERA"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    taxNumber: "78903228",
    name: "CARLOS PEREZ GONZALEZ"
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    taxNumber: "176812737",
    name: "ANDRES VIÑALES CIENFUEGOS"
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    taxNumber: "216352696",
    name: "OSCAR PEREZ ZUÑIGA"
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    taxNumber: "78684747",
    name: "JOAQUIN ANDRADE SANDOVAL"
  },
];

const paddocks = [{
    paddockManagerId: 6,
    farmId: 1,
    paddockTypeId: 2,
    harvestYear: 2012,
    area: 10587,
  },
  {
    paddockManagerId: 2,
    farmId: 2,
    paddockTypeId: 2,
    harvestYear: 2018,
    area: 16750,
  },
];

const farms = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "AGRICOLA SANTA ANA"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "VINA SANTA PAULA"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "FORESTAL Y AGRICOLA LO ENCINA"
  },
];



const farmManagerNames = () => {
  const nameFarms = farms.map((farm) => {
    const idFarms = paddocks.map((paddock) => {
      const nameManager = paddockManagers.map((manager) => {
        if (farm.id === paddock.farmId) {
          return [farm.name, manager.name]
        }
      })
    })
  })
  console.log(nameFarms);
};
console.log(farmManagerNames())
farmManagerNames();
```

Este es el resultado esperado :

```
       [
 {  "AGRICOLA SANTA ANA" : JUAN TAPIA BURGOS, JOAQUIN ANDRADE SANDOVAL},
 {  "VINA SANTA PAULA" : CARLOS PEREZ GONZALEZ, JOAQUIN ANDRADE SANDOVAL},
 {  "FORESTAL Y AGRICOLA LO ENCINA" :JUAN TAPIA BURGOS},
 ];
```

Muchas gracias y saludos !!

Comment: Buen día, te recomiendo hacer el [tour] y leer la sección [ask]. Sería bueno que agregaras un ejemplo del resultado esperado para entender mejor lo que deseas hacer.

Comment: Comprendo, muchas gracias lo volvere a preguntar

Comment: Puedes oprimir [edit] y agregar la información en la misma pregunta sin tener que crear una nueva

Comment: Muchas gracias, ahi lo modifique para que se entienda mejor, gracias por el feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías resolverlo así:

1. Usando [`array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) recorremos el arreglos de `famrs`.
2. Usando [`array.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) sobre `paddocks` obtenemos el `paddock` que corresponde al `farm.id`.
3. Usando `array.find` sobre `paddockManagers` obtenemos el `manager` que corresponde al `paddock.paddockManagerId`.
4. Creamos un objeto cuya clave sea el `farm.name` y su valor el `manager.name` y lo retornamos.

#### Ejemplo:

```js
const paddockManagers = [{
    id: 1,
    taxNumber: "132254524",
    name: "JUAN TAPIA BURGOS"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    taxNumber: "143618668",
    name: "EFRAIN SOTO VERA"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    taxNumber: "78903228",
    name: "CARLOS PEREZ GONZALEZ"
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    taxNumber: "176812737",
    name: "ANDRES VIÑALES CIENFUEGOS"
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    taxNumber: "216352696",
    name: "OSCAR PEREZ ZUÑIGA"
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    taxNumber: "78684747",
    name: "JOAQUIN ANDRADE SANDOVAL"
  },
];

const paddocks = [{
    paddockManagerId: 6,
    farmId: 1,
    paddockTypeId: 2,
    harvestYear: 2012,
    area: 10587,
  },
  {
    paddockManagerId: 2,
    farmId: 2,
    paddockTypeId: 2,
    harvestYear: 2018,
    area: 16750,
  },
  {
    paddockManagerId: 1,
    farmId: 3,
    paddockTypeId: 2,
    harvestYear: 2018,
    area: 16750,
  },
];

const farms = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "AGRICOLA SANTA ANA"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "VINA SANTA PAULA"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "FORESTAL Y AGRICOLA LO ENCINA"
  },
];

//
const farmManagerNames = () => {
  // Paso 1
  return farms.map((farm) => {
    // Paso 2
    const paddock = paddocks.find(p => p.farmId == farm.id),
      // Paso 3
      manager = paddockManagers.find(m => m.id == paddock.paddockManagerId);
    // Paso 4
    return {
      [farm.name]: manager.name
    }
  })
};
console.log(farmManagerNames());
```

**PD**: El resultado que buscas obtener no es posible ya que estaría faltando información para armarlo.